# extract line from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to extract this line of code from a script i am retrieving via ajax..

this line `new Date(2010, 10 - 1, 31, 23, 59, 59)`  from

```
jQuery(function () { jQuery('#dealCountdown').countdown({ 
until: new Date(2010, 10 - 1, 31, 23, 59, 59), 
serverSync: serverTime, 
timezone: +11, 
compact: true, 
format: 'HMS', 
expiryUrl: BASE, 
layout: '
```

Is it possible to do this with jquery.  The jquery selector won't let me manipulate script tags.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use javascript's native function `String.match`:

```
importantline = "" + ajax_data.match(/until:\s.*,/);
importantline = importantline.replace(/^until:|,$/gi, "");
```

`importantline` should have the string you need

I added a jsfiddle to make clear it works: http://jsfiddle.net/elektronikLexikon/3eZAf/

Comment: awesome.. i've tried it.. it comes back with 
until: new Date(2010,
followed by importantline.replace is not a function for the second line.. im assuming something is up with the comma?

Comment: this importantline = responseText.match(/until:\s.*,/);

gives me "until: new Date(2010, 10 - 1, 31, 23, 59, 59),"

Comment: oh, my fault... the `?` is wrong here. But does the replace function work now?

Comment: now I know what is wrong: the first function does not return a String, so just put a `"" +` before the function call to make it a string (I'll edit it).